# Can't access instrument view in Arturia Analog Lab 2

Tags: software

I bought an Arturia KeyLab 61 hybrid synthesizer which was supplied with Analog Lab 2. I have an issue here: I can't access an instrument view.

Here is like it's supposed be:
[image: Right way]

And here's a screenshot from my version of the software:

[image: Wrong way]

You can clearly see, that I don't have that small third button on the right – instrument view. How can I make it to show up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to buy the full instrument product from Arturia or buy the Analog Collectiom product which includes all the instruments. You have the free software that just has presets that you can play to entice you to buy the full software packages.